# Firebug not stopping at breakpoint in mac os x

Tags: javascript, macos, firefox, firebug

Firebug is giving me strange behavior and i don't know if there is something with my code or if it's a bug in firebug.

The problem i'm having is that firebug does not stop on a simple breakpoint. However, if i add a watch expression it does show me the value of that, so i know that my code is working and something other must be at play here.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="nl">
<head>
    <title>DOM API</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="t.a.v. klant: plaats keywords gescheiden door een comma">
    <meta name="description" content="t.a.v. klant: Wordt gebruikt door google als omschrijving in de zoekresultaten">
    <meta name="author" content="klantnaam">

    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/nav-popup.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>  

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.site.nl/images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/ios-icon.png"><!--ios web app icon 114x114--> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="all">  

    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!--pluginSyntax-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pluginSyntax/scripts/shCore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pluginSyntax/scripts/shBrushJScript.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pluginSyntax/scripts/shBrushXml.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pluginSyntax/scripts/shBrushCss.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pluginSyntax/scripts/shBrushJScript.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="js/pluginSyntax/styles/shCoreDefault.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">SyntaxHighlighter.all();</script>
    <!--pluginSyntax-->

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>

<!--level1-->
<div class="level1">
<!--level1-->

    <h1>DOM</h1>

    <p>The Document Object Model (DOM) is a programming interface for HTML. It provides a structured representation of the document (a tree) and it defines a way that the structure can be accessed from programs so that they can change the document structure, style and content. The DOM provides a representation of the document as a structured group of nodes and objects that have properties and methods.</p>

    <p>In the DOM every part of a web page is represented as a <code>node</code>. There are 3 nodes:</p>

    <ul id="jow">
        <li><code>Element</code> nodes (h1 tag)</li>
        <li><code>Attribute</code> nodes (class="heading")</li>
        <li><code>Text</code> nodes (Title of this tutorial)</li>
    </ul>

<!--level1-->
</div>
<!--level1-->

<script>

 var ieps = document.getElementById("jow");

 for (var member in ieps){

    if(ieps.hasOwnProperty(member)){
        alert(ieps[member]);
    }

}

</script>
```

I have set a breakpoint on the declaration of the var ieps and offcourse firebug does not stop there and just reloads the page.

Any ideas?

Thx...

Comment: Does this happen on other websites, too?

Comment: Just tried it on stackoverflow. Firebug works as expected...

Comment: Even the native firefox debugger doesn't stop at the breakpoint... strange...